# Flash AS3 : Get Facebook like page's Like Count

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, facebook

I want to display the like count of a page on my flash application. **"When loading my flash app I can send and load a url which can return the count information of the like page"**

anyone know the soultion for this?

Comment: Request a page with AS3 that uses the PHP SDK + the Graph API (which will let you get the page likes easily). For reference: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy. You just query the link http://graph.facebook.com/?id=[YOUR_SITE] and it'll return a piece of JSON like this:

```
{
   "id": "YOUR_URL",
   "shares": 11
}
```

So if you wanted to get the shares for Google, just query http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com (you can click on the link itself as well).

Use the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class to load in the data and the [AS3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) to convert the JSON to an Object.

Answer (score 0):

if all you are concerned about is retreiving the `likes` value from the JSON object, instead of going thru the trouble of using the JSON parser from AS3CoreLib you could instead just simply read the loaded data as a string and parse it using a regular expression:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteEventHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/google"));

function loaderCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("Google Likes: " + evt.currentTarget.data.match(new RegExp("\"likes\":(\\d+),"))[1]);
}

//Google Likes: 3782518
```

Answer (score 0):

**as3 :**

```
phpVar.id = "like";
phpVar.selectsize = selectedSize;
phpURLr.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
phpURLr.data = phpVar;      
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
phpLoader.load(phpURLr);
```

**php :**

```
if($_SESSION['test']==''){
            $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
            echo " cond 1 ";
        }
        else {
            echo " cond 2 ";
            $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test']+1;
        }
        echo " test value = ".$_SESSION['test'];
```

......